# Get custom column(s)/field(s) with Google Adwords script

Tags: javascript, google-ads-api, awql

I am currently working on a script to report information on our Ad Groups. We set up some customized columns and it would be great to get them while creating the reports.

A basic code based on the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/appendix/reports/adgroup-performance-report#adgroupname) looks like this:

```
var report = AdWordsApp.report(
    'SELECT CampaignName, AdGroupName, MyCustomColumn ' +
    'FROM   ADGROUP_PERFORMANCE_REPORT ' +
    'WHERE  CampaignName CONTAINS "'+campaign_discriminator+'"');

var rows = report.rows();
while (rows.hasNext()) {
    var row = rows.next();
    Logger.log(JSON.stringify(row));
}
```

However, I did not find anyway to get the custom column (`MyCustomColumn` here) in this Adwords Query Language (AWQL) request. I looked around on the web and this question seems not covered, is the answer too obvious or just impossible?

Thank you for any useful input and questions

Best.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's impossible I am afraid.

AWQL supports only the report types, columns, etc. defined here: https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/appendix/reports

You'd need to implement the logic that defines the custom column in your script code

Comment: It looks like you are right, I just found [a similar link](https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/appendix/reports/all-reports) listing all the fields and this looks not possible. Thank you for your input.